# Overlapping partitions?

Tags: partitioning

Please help: I probably am blind :-)

Running "partprobe /dev/sda" gives the error:

`Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.`

If I dump structure using "sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.txt", I get:

`/dev/sda1 : start=       63, size=    80262, Id=de
/dev/sda2 : start=    81920, size=  4194304, Id= c, bootable
/dev/sda3 : start=  4276224, size=  2048000, Id=83
/dev/sda4 : start=  6324224, size=1556054016, Id= 5
/dev/sda5 : start=  6326272, size=983040000, Id=83
/dev/sda6 : start=989368320, size=819200000, Id=83
/dev/sda7 : start=1808570368, size= 32913408, Id=82
/dev/sda8 : start=1841485824, size=110962688, Id=83
/dev/sda9 : start=1952448575, size=1952448449, Id=83
/dev/sda10: start=3904897087, size=1952448449, Id=83`

If I run "sfdisk -V /dev/sda" I get the following error:

`sfdisk: Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
Warning: partition 6 is not contained in partition 6`

Additional information about the partitions:

`Disk /dev/sda: 2999.0 GB, 2998960914432 bytes, 5857345536 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4501af55`

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *       81920     4276223     2097152    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda3         4276224     6324223     1024000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4         6324224  1562378239   778027008    5  Extended
/dev/sda5         6326272   989366271   491520000   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       989368320  1808568319   409600000   83  Linux
/dev/sda7      1808570368  1841483775    16456704   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8      1841485824  1952448511    55481344   83  Linux
/dev/sda9      1952448575  3904897023   976224224+  83  Linux
/dev/sda10     3904897087  5857345535   976224224+  83  Linux

Where is the overlapping? I just can't see!!!

Comment: Use `sfdisk -l /dev/sda > sda.txt` and read the start/end boundaries, that'll help you to ID the overlap/

Comment: I've updated with fdisk -l /devsda... Would be the problem the end of sda4 (which is the extended partition), shall it be beyone end of sda10?

Comment: I am confused. You show a 3TiB drive? But have MBR (msdos) partitioning? MBR only works up to 2TiB, then you have to use gpt partitioning. And drive starts at sector 63 indicating it is an old drive as Since Windows 7, bit later with Linux drives start at sector 2048.  Also sfdisk output is from older version as new versions support gpt & have more data. What version of Ubuntu?  All logical partitions (sda5 & above) must be inside the extended partition. Yours are not.

Comment: I'ts a RAID 5 hardware setup. There 4 1TB drives, so 3TB is available. probable first is where Dell saves information about raid. Second is my /boot and is using ext4 - I can't tell why it is FAT32, probably just id issue, is not affecting my system by today.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is your drive structure. Notice the sda4–6 mismatch

Comment: Thanks for the helpful visualization. Nevertheless, I think problem is that sda4 shall be ending at sda10 ends.

Answer (score 0):

At least `sda4` and `sda5` are overlapping. `sd4` takes up 6324224 to 1562378240, while `sd5` starts at 6326272.

Comment: sda4 is a extended partition... I forgot to mention... I'll update the original post...
sda5, sda6, sda7, sda8, sda9, sda10 are inside sda4.
But you gave me a great idea: to check if sda4 is big enough.

Comment: @EdsonRichter it's not, you can tell that clearly by the "End" sector of /dev/sda4 being LOWER than the uppermost "start".  Your extended partition only partially covers /dev/sda6 and the rest are not within it.  So you've got a broken partition setup here.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasWard. I think this is exactly problem I'm facing: I should put sda4 end = sda10 end, then it will be fixed.